# Adding an additional letter matching group to an existing regex

Tags: javascript, regex, path

I have the following regex: `(?:\/us)?\/[a-z]{2}[_-][a-z]{2}(?:\/?$|(?=\/))|\/[a-z]{2}(?:\/?$|(?=\/))^([a-z]{2}\/retail)`

As you can see, it's not particularly easy on the eyes. You can see it in action here: https://regex101.com/r/4AZwuP/1 (enable substitutions to see the desired result - the removal of matches)

Here's a few entries it's supposed to match:

```
/us/en_us/retail/en (matches /us/ and /us/en_us/)
/us/en_us/retail (matches /us/ and /en_us/)
/gb/en_gb/retail/en-uk (matches /en_gb and /en-uk)
```

Note that, these are just prefixes and the full url might look something like:

`/de/de_de/retail/de_de/products/catalog`

The goal is to run the regex and delete matches so that this lines becomes:

`de/retail/products/catalog`

**The above Regex accomplishes this with one exception: in the first example, I need it to match not only `/us/en_us` but also `/en` (or `/de` or `/mx` - in other words, there's an additional country code there; it unfortunately does not.**

What I do know for a fact is that if those two characters are present, it'll be one of these two:

- `.../retail/en`
- `.../retail/en/something/or/other`

In either case it's always two characters either alone or followed by a forward slash.

##### How can I modify the original regex to deal with this annoying edge case?

Bonus: how does the original work?

Answer (score 1):

If a lookbehind [is supported](https://caniuse.com/js-regexp-lookbehind) you might use:

```
(?:\/[a-z]{2})?\/[a-z]{2}[-_][a-z]{2}\b|(?<=\/retail)\/[a-z]{2}\b
```

- `(?:\/[a-z]{2})?` Optionally match `/` and 2 chars a-z
- `\/[a-z]{2}[-_][a-z]{2}\b` Match `/` 2 chars a-z. Then either `-` or `_` and 2 char a-z
- `|` Or
- `(?<=\/retail)\/[a-z]{2}\b` Match 2 chars a-z asserting `/retail` directly to the left

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/knPNDm/1)

Or use a capture group, and in the callback of replace check if group 1 exists. If it does, use it in the replacement to keep it.

```
(?:\/[a-z]{2})?\/[a-z]{2}[-_][a-z]{2}\b|\/(retail)\/[a-z]{2}\b
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/zFEoao/1)

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you want remove country code.then the begin `/gb` is country code also.
My regex is this `(\/\w{2}(?=\/|$))|(\/\w{2}(-|_)\w{2}(?=\/|$))`

let break in into two `regex`

- `(\/\w{2}(?=\/|$))` match two letter after `/` and end with `/` or nothing
- `(\/\w{2}(-|_)\w{2}(?=\/|$))` match two letter plus `_|-` and plus two letter,also start with `/` end with `/`

it match all example in your `regex101`,but it will failed if there has other two letters in your url

Comment: I changed your regex slightly - https://regex101.com/r/myxtvF/1 - as you can see it doesn't match /en at the end there, which was my question

Comment: hey,I follow your needs,change the regex.https://regex101.com/r/HDiCda/1